# Aiflow skipping task on ONE_SUCCESS trigger rule

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I am using one_success trigger rule so that if anyone of the parent task passes than the child task run which is happening as expected. However, I am getting issue when both are getting failed. In this case, child task is getting skipped instead of fail. Below is the dag implementation

```
import logging
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.hive_operator import HiveOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.sensors.web_hdfs_sensor import WebHdfsSensor
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule


circles = ['101','102','103']

def load_hive_partition(circle, **kwargs):

        return HiveOperator(
                    task_id='add_partition_{}'.format(circle),
                    hql='alter table abc.def add partition (event_date="{{ ds }}", circle="'+circle+'") location "/user/cloudera/hive/abc/def/event_date={{ ds }}/circle='+circle+'"',
                    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_SUCCESS,
                    dag=dag)

def check_hdfs_node1(circle, **kwargs):
    return WebHdfsSensor(
    task_id='source_data_sensor_node1_{}'.format(circle),
    webhdfs_conn_id='webhdfs_default_1',
    filepath='/user/cloudera/hive/abc/def/event_date={{ds}}/circle='+circle,
    timeout=60 * 60 * 24,
    dag=dag
)

def check_hdfs_node2(circle, **kwargs):
    return WebHdfsSensor(
    task_id='source_data_sensor_node2_{}'.format(circle),
    webhdfs_conn_id='webhdfs_default',
    filepath='/user/cloudera/hive/abc/def/event_date={{ds}}/circle='+circle,
    timeout=60 * 60 * 24,
    dag=dag
)

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'run_as_user': 'airflow',
    'retries': 3,
    'start_date': datetime(year=2020, month=8, day=30),
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=10)
}

dag = DAG(dag_id="HiveLoadPartition_circle",
          default_args=args,
          schedule_interval='30 18 * * *',
          catchup=False)

kinit_bash = BashOperator(
        task_id='kinit_bash',
        bash_command='kinit -kt /usr/local/airflow/keytab.keytab appuser@cloudera.com',
        dag=dag)



#start_dag = DummyOperator(task_id='start_dag', dag=dag)
end_dag = DummyOperator(task_id='end_dag',trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE, dag=dag)


for circle in circles:
    add_partition = load_hive_partition(circle)
    check_hdfs_1 = check_hdfs_node1(circle)
    check_hdfs_2 = check_hdfs_node2(circle)
    check_hdfs_1.set_upstream(kinit_bash)
    check_hdfs_2.set_upstream(kinit_bash)
    add_partition.set_upstream(check_hdfs_1)
    add_partition.set_upstream(check_hdfs_2)
    end_dag.set_upstream(add_partition)
```

Graph view

[image]

How can I make my hiveload task fail in case of both of hdfs_sensor fails?

**UPDATE:**

I have also tried using trigger rule all_done in end dag. Even then it is triggering end_dag when parent task skips.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's possible - why do you try to achieve this? Would you like to send a failure email or something?

Comment: Your dag isn't connected. Also, there are a lot of missing code/typos - add_partition definition, check_hdfs_1. Correct it and update the question.

Comment: @PhilippJohannis, yes incase both branch failed i have to fail whole dag and send the email.

Comment: @SuhasNM, Updated correct dag with graph view

Comment: I tried your code and it is working as expected. end_task status is 'Upstream Failed'.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this same issue and believe it is an underlying issue with airflow. I've opened up the following PR to fix this https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/15467

2021-05-04: the fix has been merged and marked for the next ([2.0.3](https://github.com/apache/airflow/milestone/32)) release.

2021-05-23: the fix has been deployed with the release of [2.1](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.1.0/changelog.html) (2.0.3 was cancelled)

Note: I've re-added my removed response to the meta conversation as I don't have the 50 required reputation to comment on the meta thread. Glancing at the [edit guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) it does not appear to have originally qualified for removal but if I've missed something and the following does not belong here please move this response to the meta thread on my behalf since I'm unable to.

As for the meta conversation: This answer was provided very much in the spirit captured by @Ivar's [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407197/how-to-handle-answers-which-point-to-a-pull-request#comment840222_407197). So it is my intent that this answer helps Ayush and anyone else who stumbles across this issue while using <= 2.0.2. However, given the strong negative (-4 votes at the time of writing) reaction to this answer next time I'll just refrain from contributing back to SO as I only have so much time in the day and it has been made clear that identifying the issue, fixing the issue, and opening a PR does not meet SO's standard. ~Cheers

Comment: This answer is being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407197/6296561)

Comment: I think you can improve this answer by explaining what was wrong, and how it was fixed.